# OpenSSL AES Symmetric Error on Key derivation

Tags: error-handling, openssl, aes

I have a simple question. I get this error when i inputted openssl enc -no salt -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:apple -P and i got an error saying: deprecated key derivation used. Using -iter or pbkdf2 would be better.  I just want to know what does this error mean? What is key derivation?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function or search for PBKDF2 will help you :-)

Comment: Thank you Michael.